# $rootScope.$broadcast not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-broadcast

I am trying to get $rootScope.$broadcast to refresh my view. 
The service is-

```
var app = angular.module("productsApp", [])
    .service("serviceProvider", function ($http) {
        this.getDatas = function getDatas(data) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST', url: serviceUrl + '/GetProductsByCategoryOrName', headers: {
                    'Authorization': apiKey
                },
                data: data
            })
        }
        return this
    }).factory("sharedService", function ($rootScope) {

        var mySharedService = {};

        mySharedService.values = [];

        mySharedService.passData = function (newData) {
            mySharedService.values = newData;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed', newData);
        }

        return mySharedService;
    });
```

**Invoking through controller-**

```
function searchProductsController($scope, $window, serviceProvider, sharedService) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var data = { "query": $scope.searchText, "categoryId": "976759", "pageIndex": 0, "sortDirection": "asc" };
        serviceProvider.getDatas(data).then(function (response) {
            var result = response;
            sharedService.passData(result.data.data);
        });
    }
};
```

here in this controller `sharedService.passData` which passes new array to service method. Then it is trying to broadcast it for the changes with the line-  `$rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed', newData)`

I don't know why it is not broadcasting the changes to view. Is there any other way to broadcast the changes?

**Note-**
My earlier question [How to transfer data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624113/how-to-transfer-data-between-controllers/35624161?noredirect=1#comment58931805_35624161) couldn't get me any help.

**Edit**

So far I've changed in the listeners-

```
mySharedService.passData = function (newData) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed', newData)
}
$rootScope.$on('dataPassed', function (newData) {
    mySharedService.values = newData;
})
```

But still can't get refreshed view.

Comment: Where is your `$scpe.$on`?

Comment: @Artless, How do I use it?

Comment: $broadcast would not directly async data on view...you need to set listner over broadcasted event using $on and then you can get broadacasted data inside callback function of it. And re assign data again to reflect it over scope.

Comment: @PankajParkar, I tried both the answers below, but none of worked for me. I am afraid I am doing something wrong with that. Can you please assist me

Comment: Below solutions should work..if you are not doing something wrong..do addd plunkr please

Comment: @PankajParkar, Can you see my edit pleaase?

Comment: Which scope variable you are using to bind data on view?

Comment: Which scope variable you are using to bind data on view?

Comment: @PankajParkar, Its of searchProductsController.

Comment: @Manoz check I've added an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104607/discussion-between-manoz-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use $broadcast or $emit. You should have $scope.$on to listen to that event.

```
$scope.$on('dataPassed', function(){ //code go here });
```

**Edit:** Update working code for question requirement

```
var app = angular.module("productsApp", [])
    .service("serviceProvider", function ($http) {
        this.getDatas = function getDatas(data) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST', url: serviceUrl + '/GetProductsByCategoryOrName', headers: {
                    'Authorization': apiKey
                },
                data: data
            });
        }
        return this
    }).factory("sharedService", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        var mySharedService = {
            values: [],
            setValues: function(data){
                if(data){
                    mySharedService.values.length = 0;
                    data.forEach(function(item){
                        mySharedService.values.push(item);
                    });    
                }
            }
        };
        return mySharedService;
    }]);      
function GetController($scope, serviceProvider, sharedService, $rootScope) {
    var shareData = sharedService;
    $scope.products = sharedService.values;
    $scope.shareData = sharedService;
    var data = { "query": "grocery", "categoryId": "976759", "pageIndex": 0, "sortDirection": "asc" };
    serviceProvider.getDatas(data).then(function (response) {
        sharedService.setValues(response.data.data);
    });
}
function searchProductsController($scope, $window, serviceProvider, sharedService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var data = { "query": $scope.searchText, "categoryId": "976759", "pageIndex": 0, "sortDirection": "asc" };
        serviceProvider.getDatas(data).then(function (response) {
            sharedService.setValues(response.data.data);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have put a listeners to listen to the broadbasted event. Broadcasted event would not directly update your view data directly on view html. You have to use `$on` over scope to bind events on scope. Inside a callback function of it. You would get an benefit to get broadcasted data & re assign that retrieve data to scope variable again to get updated binding.

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module("productsApp", [])
  .service("serviceProvider", function($http) {
  this.getDatas = function getDatas(data) {
    return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: serviceUrl + '/GetProductsByCategoryOrName',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': apiKey
      },
      data: data
    })
  }
  return this;
}).factory("sharedService", ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

  var mySharedService = {};

  mySharedService.values = [];

  mySharedService.passData = function(newData) {
    mySharedService.values = newData;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed', newData)
  }

  return mySharedService;
}]);

function GetController($scope, serviceProvider, sharedService, $rootScope) {
  var data = {
    "query": "grocery",
    "categoryId": "976759",
    "pageIndex": 0,
    "sortDirection": "asc"
  };
  serviceProvider.getDatas(data).then(function(response) {
    sharedService.passData(response.data.data);
  });
  //listener should register when controller loads
  $scope.$on('dataPassed', function(event, newData) {
    sharedService.values = newData;
    $scope.products = sharedService.values;
  })
}

function searchProductsController($scope, $window, serviceProvider, sharedService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
      var data = {
        "query": $scope.searchText,
        "categoryId": "976759",
        "pageIndex": 0,
        "sortDirection": "asc"
      };
      serviceProvider.getDatas(data).then(function(response) {
        var result = response;
        sharedService.passData(result.data.data);
      });
    }
    //listener should register when controller loads
    $scope.$on('dataPassed', function(event, newData) {
      console.log(newData);
      sharedService.values = newData;
    })
};
```

Comment: How do I access $scope in service?

Comment: No you shouldn't.. Above code you should put inside a controller

Comment: Can you please view my js on stackoverflow group chat please? I am still not getting this work

Answer (score 1):

You should listen what you are broadcasting :

```
$rootScope.$on('dataPassed', function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

This reference may help : [Why do we use $rootScope.$broadcast in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

**@Manoz** as for you previous answer also, i had given you the answer. I have updated the plunker for that as well. And as for using `$rootscope.`, you have 2 params, in which one is event and the next is the data you are broadcasting. I have mocked your api call in both the answers to make you more understand.

Here is plunker using `$rootscope`:http://plnkr.co/edit/MBzDMRll5Z4CjusY5QLN?p=preview

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
      <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

      <div ng-app = "app" >

           <div ng-controller="searchProductsController">
             <input ng-model="searchText"/>
                <button ng-click="setPlace(searchText)">Enter Search id</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="GetController">
              <div ng-repeat="product in products">
                                <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
      </div>


<script>
         var app = angular.module('app', []);
         app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
              $rootScope.test = 123;
            }]);

        app.factory("Service", function ($rootScope) {
            function passData(newData) {
              alert('i am here');
               $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed', newData);
            }
            return {
                passData: passData
            }
        }).factory("dataService",function($http){//mock for getting values from api
          return{
            getComments:function (roomid){
                   if(roomid==1){
                     var data = [{"name":"alex","place":"kathmandu"},{"name":"god","place":"seattle"}];
                     return data;
                   }
                   if(roomid==2)
                   {
                     var newdata = [{"name":"newname","place":"kathmandu"},{"name":"newname2","place":"seattle"}];
                     return newdata;
                   }
              }
          }
        });
        app.controller('searchProductsController',function($scope, Service,$http,dataService) {
            $scope.setPlace = function (searchText) {
                var newdata = dataService.getComments(searchText);
                Service.passData(newdata);
            }
        })
        .controller('GetController',function($scope, Service,$rootScope) {
          $rootScope.$on('dataPassed', function (event,args) {
                $scope.products = args;
            })
        })
              </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a very little, but very effective, mistake. Change your listener from this:

```
$rootScope.$on('dataPassed', function (newData) {
    mySharedService.values = newData;
});
```

To this:

```
$rootScope.$on('dataPassed', function ($event, newData) {
    mySharedService.values = newData;
});
```

On any AngularJS scope event dispatched, the first argument for every listener is one $event object.

I'm surprised that one old question, with this many answers, haven't noticed the real issue.