# OnClick `ngClick` of icon we are `broadcasting` the `refresh` event. But Its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angular and jquery float to draw a graph. Graph is canvas element.

I want to re-draw a canvas on click of some icon..
clicked handler is `toggleSideMenu`. OnClick `ngClick` of icon we are `broadcasting` the `refresh` event. But Its not working.

If I will put debbugger inside the function it works..

My JS Code-

```
 this.toggleSideMenu = function () {
    //  this.setSideMenuState(!this.sidemenu);
    $("#sidemenu-canvas").toggleClass("toggled");
    $timeout(function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("refresh");
    }, 50);
    $timeout(function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("render");
    }, 50);
  };
```

Instead of giving -

```
$timeout(function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("refresh");
    }, 50);
```

I have given

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("refresh");
```

I have listner also-

```
$scope.$on('refresh', function() {
         if(!$scope.isDRPDisabled) {
           $scope.refresh();

      });
```

But its not working.
Please help me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$rootScope.$broadcast not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644084/rootscope-broadcast-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

When you use $broadcast or $emit. You should have $rootScope.$on to listen to that event. For more please follow the below link. Please consider searching in stack over flow before posting any question.

[$rootScope.$broadcast not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644084/rootscope-broadcast-not-working)

Comment: Note that OP broadcasts on $rootScope, thus should have a $rootScope.$on.

Answer (score 0):

You broadcast on $rootScope, and your listener is on $scope. These are two different "scopes" and can't listen to eachother's broadcasts. Unless you want a different controller to catch your refresh event, I suggest keeping the broadcast within the $scope. Like:

```
this.toggleSideMenu = function () {
    //  this.setSideMenuState(!this.sidemenu);
    $("#sidemenu-canvas").toggleClass("toggled");
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.$broadcast("refresh");
    }, 50);
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.$broadcast("render");
    }, 50);
};
```

But otherwise your listener should be $rootScope as well.